# How to set only the vertical frame using view.layer.borderwidth

Tags: ios, uitableview, view

I wanted to ask if there is a way to set only the vertical layer.borderwidth and not all the frame,

right now i'm using

```
selectedTableDish.layer.borderWidth = 2
```

which will frame my entire view,
I want to change the width only for the vertical parts

the reason I want to use this and not drawing an actual line on the side of my view is because it's a table view and when I scroll it down, my lines I create will also scroll the frame won't cover all my tableview

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440934/ios-uiview-border-bottom-width) and [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8573893/7104617)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CALayer: add a border only at one side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022656/calayer-add-a-border-only-at-one-side)